# Run configuration in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

What's going on this image.
What's wrong with the run configuration?

Android studio run configuration :

[image]

I have downloaded 
SDK tools,
SDK build tools,
platform,
platform tools,
android support repository,
google USB drivers,
gradle,
with latest versions

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First try in Android Studio:

```
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```